# java - How to match the details of a Dialog from RecyclerViewAdapter to another Fragment upon clicking the button

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android coding, I've tried all the possible solution here and on YouTube but still struggling. I just want how to match the data from a dialog of a fragment to another fragment upon pressing the button. we're working on a simple project. :)

> Here is what we want to do.Kindly watch this link:
>   https://i.stack.imgur.com/70NxE.jpg

We want to change the name that will match the dialog upon clicking the "set parameters' button

here's what we found online the difference is we have a dialog button
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZXoGG2XTjzU
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69C1ljfDvl0

> Here are the codes
>   RecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

Context mContext;
List<specieList> mData;
Dialog myDialog;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<specieList> mData) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mData = mData;
}


@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v;
    Button b;

    v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);
    final MyViewHolder vHolder = new MyViewHolder(v);

    myDialog = new Dialog(mContext);
    myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.fishpop);
    myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    b = myDialog.findViewById(R.id.toasted);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            TextView toastfish = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_fish_id);
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"Parameters are now set for " + toastfish.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // here upon clicking this button click we want to match the details in this dialog to another tab. Kindly watch the link above :)
        }
    });



    vHolder.fish_choices.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            TextView dialog_fish = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_fish_id);
            TextView dialog_sciname = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_sciname_id);
            ImageView dialog_image = (ImageView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_image_id);
            dialog_fish.setText(mData.get(vHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getFish());
            dialog_sciname.setText(mData.get(vHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getSciname());
            dialog_image.setImageResource(mData.get(vHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getImage());
            myDialog.show();
        }
    });
    return vHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.tv_fish.setText(mData.get(position).getFish());
    holder.tv_sciname.setText(mData.get(position).getSciname());
    holder.img.setImageResource(mData.get(position).getImage());

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private LinearLayout fish_choices;
    private TextView tv_fish;
    private TextView tv_sciname;
    private ImageView img;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
            fish_choices = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.choices);
            tv_fish = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tv_sciname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            img = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);

    }
}
```

}

> Code for overview tab(This tab we want to match the content)

```
public class overview extends Fragment {

View v2;


// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public overview() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment overview.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static overview newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    overview fragment = new overview();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_overview, container, false);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    String currentDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(calendar.getTime());
    String currentTime = time.format(calendar.getTime());


    TextView textViewDate =(TextView) v2.findViewById(R.id.date_id);
    textViewDate.setText(currentDate);
    TextView textViewTime =(TextView) v2.findViewById(R.id.time_id);
    textViewTime.setText(currentTime);



    return v2;
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

}

> Code for Specie tab (this tab we want to refer)

```
public class specie extends Fragment {

View v;

private RecyclerView myrecyclerview;
private List<specieList> lstspecie;


// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;



public specie() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment specie.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static specie newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    specie fragment = new specie();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    lstspecie = new ArrayList<>();
    lstspecie.add(new specieList("Nile Tilapia", "Oreochromis niloticus", R.drawable.tilapia));
    lstspecie.add(new specieList("Ayungin (Silver Perch)", "Bidyanus bidyanus", R.drawable.ayungin));
    lstspecie.add(new specieList("Sugpo (Tiger Prawn)", "Penaeus monodon", R.drawable.hipon));
    lstspecie.add(new specieList("Hito (Catfish)", "Siluriformes", R.drawable.hito));
    lstspecie.add(new specieList("Giant Gourami", "Osphronemus goramy", R.drawable.giant));
    lstspecie.add(new specieList("Bangus (Milkfish)", "Chanos chanos", R.drawable.bangus));


    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);

    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_specie, container, false);
    myrecyclerview = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.specie_recycleview);
    RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), lstspecie);
    myrecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    myrecyclerview.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
    return v;
}


// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

}

> Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Call below method on your button click..

```
     public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameContainer, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragment.toString());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

pass **frameContainer** in constructor of your **Adapter** like..

```
new RecyclerViewAdapter(context, list, R.id.frameContainer);
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for this, we have try this method in my button click in the dialog but still struggling, may we know another part to place or call the code. We have also updated the post/problem. Thank you!

Comment: hi! We got an error in getSupportFragmentManager(); 'Cannot Resolved Method'.
We researched that you need AppCompatActivity to do that but our button is in a Adapter and couldn't extend. Kindly give an advice how to do it thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Using object oriented Approach**

You can write a function in your activity and you can call a fragment's method from it, as you have your Fragment's reference in your Activity when you initialized it like

In Your Activity

```
   class yourActivity ... {

       // your other methods

      public void callFragmentMethod(String params) {

           // here call your fragment's method
           fragment.method(params);
      }

   }
```

In your Fragment now

```
   class yourFragment ... {

       // your other methods

      public void method(String params) {

           // here call your fragment's method
           here do whatever you want to do it with params
      }

   }
```

Now you can call your Activity's method either from another fragment or from Adapter, whatever you want

From Fragment you can call like

```
((yourActivity)getActivity()).callFragmentMethod(params);
```

From Adapter

```
((yourActivity)context).callFragmentMethod(params);
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for this, we have try this method but we cant call the other tab to perform a method upon clicking the button in the dialog. May we know something to put in this code so we can match the content(text and image) to another tab. Thanks!

public void onClick(View view) {
            TextView toastfish = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_fish_id);
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"Parameters are now set for " + toastfish.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           
        }

Comment: are you able to call clicklistener when the dialog button is clicked? or that is also problematic?

Comment: yeah we can call it we just don't know what code to put to link the dialog button to another tab

Comment: first of all you need to add click listener to dialog button, 2nd. from that function, call the activity's method in which both fragments are shown, now at last from activity function call the other fragment function.

Comment: Hi! we already have the clickListener in the dialog button. The button is inside a RecyclerViewAdapter. We are thinking of calling a fragment in the onClick method of the button to match its content. Any advice how to do it and where do we put the codes specifically? We're new to this and very confused, we're glad for your help :)